# Conflict files on mac

Tags: git, macos, merge-conflict-resolution, winmerge

I'm sure a similar question exists but this question is kinda specific for Macs and Conflict files. So Mac supports git-diff tools but I'm looking for a native mac tool that supports reading conflict files with conflict markers like winmerge..

so try saving this text in a file and open it with your favorite merge tool on mac and compare it with winmerge's output see if it can understand the format (Right now we use winmerge on mac with wine) I was wondering if there is a Native mac tool that can do this, sounds pretty trivial considering the fact that there are plenty of merge tools for mac.

PS: Again I understand that you can configure git or other version management tools to split the file and open it as 3 separate files for merging but I'm looking for a Mac program that can understand the conflict file natively.

```
the number of planets are
<<<<<<< HEAD
nine
=======
eight
>>>>>>> branch-a
```

Comment: The Mac running a variant of BSD UNIX, git is as native as it can possibly get. While trying to chew that, consider revisiting the help section of SO, especially the part discussing what is [the topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @SamiLaine thanks for replying.. I'm looking for a Native Mac Program (One that I don't have to run with wine) that can read conflict files for merging (git exists as a native binary for Mac no question about that).